# Referencing elements from a css stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I am teaching myself css and html and I created a stylesheet and broke it up into different elements (background image, cursors, etc). I am referencing the entire css file in the main html file but when I run the application I get a blank screen. What am I missing? Here is my code. First, the stylesheet

```
html, body
{
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#background
{
    background-image: url("../Assets/Graphics/background.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#mycursor
{
    cursor: url(../Assets/Graphics/cursor.cur), auto;   
}
```

And now the html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Destiny Saga</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/style.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="Assets/Graphics/title.ico" />
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't see anything, because there's nothing to show! Or does the JavaScript routine create some output?

Comment: @MannfromReno — The end tag for img elements is forbidden.

Comment: After your edit, there's even less to show. There might be an icon in the location bar, but that's it.

Comment: @Quentin Well, the rest of it looks like XHTML, so the `<img>` tag should have been self-closing. But the matter is moot now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you probably meant:

```
html, body {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#background {<--It is Bad to name an ID background... you probably want to just do div here...--> 
    background-image: url("../Assets/Graphics/background.jpg");
    background-color: #cccccc;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#mycursor { <---you could just add cursor to the above so that it will be like that in the above div-->
    cursor: url(../Assets/Graphics/cursor.cur), auto;   
}
And now the html file:

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style/style.css" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./Assets/Graphics/title.ico" />
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="background">
<h1> Hello World</h1>
        <div id="mycursor">
</div>
</div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./Javascript/Main.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Aren't those HTML comments in the CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Things that are certainly wrong:

- The `img` element is missing a `src` attribute
- The `#mycursor` selector matches an element with `id="mycursor"` and you have `id="#mycursor"`
- The `#background` ruleset doesn't match any element

You might have other issues (such as incorrect URLs).

In short, there is nothing in your HTML that should create a visible effect, and none of the styles that apply to it will change that.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<img id="#mycursor">
```

to:

```
<img id="mycursor">
```

In css you use # for ids, but in html you dont have to write the #

Comment: While this is certainly one of the problems in the source, it's not _the_ problem.